# $V/\ker(T-5I)$ is nilpotent.

Tags: jordan-normal-form

A linear operator $T$  on a complex vector space $V$ has characteristic polynomial $x^3(x-5)^2$ and minimal polynomial $x^3(x-5)$. Choose  correct options.

1. The operator induced by $T$ on quotient space $V/\ker(T-5I)$ is nilpotent. Where $I$ is the identity operator.
2. The operator induced by $T$ on quotient space $V/\ker(T-5I)$ is a scalar multiple of the identity operator.

My attempt:

From given information, we get $$T = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now $$T-5I = \begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -5 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$. Here we see that $\operatorname{Rank}(T-5I) = 3$ and by Rank-nullity theorem, $dim\ker(T-5I) = 2$

I have no more knowledge how to proceed it further. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the Jordan normal form theorem implies that there's a basis $e_1,\dots,e_5$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ in this basis is what you gave.

Then, especially after calculating the dimension of the kernel, you can read off that specfically $K:=\ker(T-5I)={\rm span}(e_4,e_5)$.

So, the cosets $e_1+K,\ e_2+K,\ e_3+K$ form a basis of the quotient space $V/K$, and $T$ acts on them as in the first $3\times 3$ block of the matrix of $T$:
$$T(e_1+K)=0+K,\quad T(e_2+K)=e_1+K,\quad T(e_3+K)=e_2+K\,.$$

Comment: Based on all these, can you write up the matrix of $T$ on $V/K$ in the given (induced) basis? Will it be maybe  a) nilpotent,  or  b)  scalar multiple of the identity?

Comment: Is matrix of T = $$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ?
$$

Comment: Not exactly. As I wrote, on the quotient space $T$ acts exactly like its $3\times 3$ submatrix $\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$. Can you see whether it's nilpotent or not?

Comment: It is nilpotent. Here I think that you have taken $ T = (e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)^t$ instead of standard basis of $\Bbb R^5$. Why you have taken $T(e_i+K) = e_{i-1} +K$ and why you have assumed $3×3$ block matrix. Don't mind , I have less knowledge about it. Although your answer is very neat and clean.

Comment: There's no mention at all on the standard basis. We choose the basis $e_1,\dots,e_5$ so that the matrix of linear operator $T$ *in that basis* is the Jordan form matrix you wrote up. Reading the columns, we see that it means exactly $T(e_1)=0,\ T(e_2)=e_1,\ T(e_3)=e_2,\ T(e_4)=5e_4,\ T(e_5)=5e_5$. The coset $e_i+K$ is the subspace $K={\rm span}(e_4,e_5)$ shifted by $e_i$. Formally it's an element of the quotient space $V/K$. Importantly, $T(K)\subseteq K$, which is needed to induce a well defined operator on $V/K$.

Comment: One more but last thing, why you have taken $T(e_i+K) = e_{i-1} +K$, $i = 1,2,3$ instead of $i =1,2,3,4,5$, consequently we get $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} $ instead of $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} $

Comment: The quotient space $V/K$ has dimension $3$. We have $e_4+K=e_5+K=K=0+K$. The cosets $e_1+K,\,e_2+K,\,e_3+K$ will form a **basis** in $V/K$. In this case (and also generally in linear algebra) taking the quotient $V\to V/K$ is pretty much like a (not necessarily orthogonal) projection to a smaller dimensional space: here we can simply forget the last two coordinates.